# Is Small Engine repair within the DIY scope?

Tags: discussion, scope

I ran across [this question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/murray-mower-with-bs-500e-engine-running-strange) in the close queue which had these comments

> I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Small Engine repair is not in the site scope.

and

> Although we do answer these questions quite often.

We've got, for instance, [lawn-mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower) (70 questions at present), which is mostly about small engines and I've never seen anyone suggest the tag, let alone the topic, was outside the site scope. It seems very DIY, as long as you're repairing a small motor (and not a vehicle, i.e. [Mechanics.SE](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/)). Community feedback would be helpful.

Comment: FWIW, [gardening.se] also has questions about [lawn mowers](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/search?q=lawn-mower) though the focus there is more operation and basic maintenance.

Comment: Mechanics.SE has a [tag for small engines](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-engine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [lawn-mower](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lawn-mower) tag here includes questions about electric mowers, the self propel mechanism, the blades of the mower, the flywheel, and other topics not necessarily specific to a small engine. For small engine repair, the most appropriate is probably [Mechanics.SE's small engine tag](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/small-engine).